# InvocationTargetException when using JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, gluon

I am trying to use Gluon/JavaFX for the first time, but I am receiving an InvocationTargetException at run-time. I have searched for answers on this site and others, but have received the same problem after trying each suggestion.

Main:

```
package Scenes;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{


    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("asdf");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }



}
```

Controller:

```
package Scenes;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;


public class Controller {

    Button kButton;
    Button bpButton;

    public void initialize() {

    }

    public static void browseFileK() {
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
        }
    }

        public static void browseFileBP() {
            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
            int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            }
        }

}
```

FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.151" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <children>
    <AnchorPane cache="true" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <children>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="155.0" layoutY="177.0" style="&#10;" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#9f9f9f" wrapText="false">
          <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
          </font>
        </Label>
            <TextField layoutX="21.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="237.0" text="Select location of Kasasa accounts file" />
            <TextField layoutX="21.0" layoutY="118.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="237.0" text="Select location of Bill Pay accounts file" />
            <Button layoutX="294.0" layoutY="48.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Browse..." />
            <Button layoutX="294.0" layoutY="115.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Browse..." />
            <Button layoutX="168.0" layoutY="269.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="253.0" text="Generate refund document" />
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Scenes.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
```

It seems the most popular suggestions have been to add the fxml file to the same package as main, add "/" in front of the fxml file, or to change the file name to "Scenes/test.fxml", none of which have worked for me.

Comment: can you include the actual error and stack trace?

Comment: I am going to guess you are not using an `IDE`. I am going to suggest you download either `NetBeans` or `Eclipse`.

Comment: I am using Eclipse. This is my first attempt at using JavaFX and I am not a professional programmer.

Comment: Can you post the project layout in your question? Your code assumes `test.fxml` is in the same package as the `Main` class.

Comment: Also, are you certain you are getting the *same* stack trace when you make these changes? If you no longer see "Location is required" you have fixed the immediate problem, and you can start to work on the next problem (your code has numerous issues).

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question depends quite a lot on what your build system is doing. Some build systems for example will not copy an `.fxml` file into the build directory if it's not in some `resources` folder instead of a source folder. Others will require explicitly specifying the file patterns that you want to copy to the build folder.

The fastest way to debug this would be to check your build folder (output directory) and see if the `.fxml` file is there.

Comment: Where exactly? If you use `getClass(...).getResource(resource)`, the class loader will search for the file in the folder corresponding to the class' package. In your case, that should be in subdirectory "Scenes" (in the same place where the `Controller.class` file is.

Comment: Also, as @SedrickJefferson pointed, you are not referring to the correct controller class. Should be `Scenes.Controller`, not `sample.Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FXML` file says :

```
fx:controller="sample.Controller"
```

but your `Controller` is in

```
 package Scenes;
```

So your `FXML` should be

```
fx:controller="Scenes.Controller"
```

You are using `Swing` components.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
```

You need to use `JavaFx` components.

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
```

Comment: That's true, but that's not why he's getting the error.

Comment: Acutally, the `Button` is causing the error. He can get away with using the `Swing` `FileChooser`.

Comment: Maybe not. I thought it was an `FXML` `Button`.

Comment: No, it's not. The error is caused by a null `Location`, which is caused by the loader unable to find the relevant `.fxml` file. This is before the controller is initialized or even loaded. Plus, he's actually using the correct `Button` class for the FXML-mapped fields.

Comment: You are right. His `FXML` does not point to the correct `Controller`.

Comment: I have made the corrections you suggested, but it is showing a similar stacktrace.

Comment: Try "S" on `scenes.Controller`

Comment: Also, make sure the `FXML` file is named `test.fxml`.

Comment: It's pretty much irrelevant what is in the FXML file if the `FXMLLoader` can't find it.

Comment: I've tried all variations of scenes and renaming the fxml file. Still no luck.

Comment: You said your file is in the `Bin` folder yet, you load your file using `"test.fxml"`.

Comment: I am guessing you are trying to create your files and project directory on your own. I think you need to download either `Netbeans` or `Eclipse`. These programs can set up your project for you.

Comment: How else would I load my files? I am using Eclipse, but the JavaFX is brand new to me.

Comment: If you are using `Eclipse` you should be able to create a new project and everything should be correct.

Comment: I haven't use `Eclipse` in forever so maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Download Netbeans. Create a new Project. Select `"JavaFX FXML Application"`.